# babel's \foreignlanguage works for Russian, but not for Serbian

Tags: babel, cyrillic

I was trying to write the Serbian alphabet using:

```
\usepackage[serbian, english]{babel}
...
\foreignlanguage{serbian}{D d}
```

But I get nothing. When I try this with e.g:

```
\usepackage[russian, english]{babel}
...
\foreignlanguage{russian}{D d}
```

I get the correct character. So for the Serbian alphabet, this is fine until I get to the letters <Џ џ/Dž dž> and <Ћ ћ/Ć ć>.

Why don't I get any character when I use Serbian, but I do when I use Russian?

Comment: Can you please make a minimal example, from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`? My test gives the expected result.

Comment: The question is unclear to me. Perhaps you're looking for the serbian characters given from `\foreignlanguage{serbian}{"D "d "C "c}`?

Comment: @egreg This is for a long essay, so I'm using lots of different packages. I'm not getting any error message though.

Comment: Or perhaps you're looking for cyrillic support for Serbian language? Babel `serbian` option only supports latin script.

Comment: @LevBishop No. That command gives me the grapheme for the digraph sometimes written as <Dj/dj>.

Comment: @LevBishop I see... Damn, so does the `russian` option conatain these Serbian Cyrillic characters?

Comment: @DangerFourpence With `\foreignlanguage{russian}{Dd}` I get, of course, "Dd", and certainly not "Дд"

Comment: Are you using `OT2` fontencoding? If so `\foreignlanguage{russian}{D d D2 d2 C1 c1}` should give access to those characters. For other fontencodings use `\CYRDZHE \CYRTSHE` etc.

Comment: @egreg that depends on which font encodings you have loaded. `russianb.ldf` has some encoding-selection magic and will switch to `OT2` if that is loaded.

Comment: @LevBishop thanks. The D2 d2 and C1 c1 solved my problem :)

Comment: @LevBishop I suspected OT2, which I wouldn't recommend. That's why I asked for a MWE and won't upvote this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the OT2 font encoding, as it appears from your scanty code, you can benefit from the following complete transliteration table, drawn from a paper of mine published on [ArsTeXnica (n. 9, April 2010)](http://www.guitex.org/home/images/ArsTeXnica/AT009/l%27arte%20esoterica%20di%20scrivere%20in%20cirillico%20con%20LATEX.pdf)

[image: Table, first half]

[image: Table, second half]

Translation of the notes:

(1) In the ligatures, the symbol `0` is the digit zero

(2) In order to split тс, use `t\/s` or `t\cydot s`

(3) All the ligatures such as `Yu` or `Ts` work also if the second letter is uppercase

Comment: thanks very much. Am I right in saying that the character that comes from the input \# is the proto-Slavic vowel _jat_?

Comment: @DangerFourpence Yes, but I wouldn't call it "protoslavic", as it was abolished only in 1917, together with the "izhitsa" and the "fita" (last part of the table).

Comment: I think it's called the proto-Slavic vowel, as it represents a vowel sound of the common Slavic language, but it might have been used as a grapheme long after this. This is more that a little off-topic though :)