# Ligatures and line breaks in OT2

Tags: line-breaking, font-encodings, rendering

I am trying to write a paper in Cyrillic using OT2, but the ligatures (nj-њ, lj-љ, dj-ђ) get broken in line breaks. Here's an example:

```latex
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1, OT2]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

Ovim jednachinama se sa velikom preciznoshc1u mozhe opisati kretanje tela \textbf{pri nerelativistichkim brzinama}, tj. pri brzinama mnogo manjim od brzine svetlosti.

\end{document}
```

It is supposed to yield this:

> Овим једначинама се са великом прецизношћу може описати кретање тела **при нерелативистичким брзинама**, тј. при брзинама много мањим од брзине светлости.

(Notice the letter њ.)

Instead, here's what I get:
[image: њ gets broken into н and ј]

As you can see, it breaks the "њ", into "н" and "ј", which is unacceptable.

**So, how do I make sure the ligature doesn't get broken?** I think it's pointless to use a `\mbox` every time there's a ligature, since that would prevent words from being broken at other places (where it is acceptable), and unnecessarily make lines longer.

Comment: You might also notice that `shc1` is rendered as 71 instead of шћ - that has been resolved [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/488864/sh-gets-rendered-as-7-using-ot2).

Comment: do you have to use the OTx encodings, they are very 1980s, you could use T2 or probably better use xelatex or lualatex and an OpenType font supporting cyrillic.

Comment: Looking at the table shown in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/100250 it appears that "n1" may be what is wanted here.  (Unfortunately, the screen I'm using isn't large enough to be sure.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I want to stick to something that can easily be transcribed between Cyrillic and Latin, and OT2 is the only familiar encoding that can do so. I only know the mere basics of (La)TeX so I work with what I'm familiar with.

Answer (score 2):

If I add `\usepackage[serbian]{babel}`, then line breaks are OK.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1, OT2]{fontenc}
\usepackage[serbian]{babel}

\begin{document}

Ovim jednachinama se sa velikom preciznosh\/c1u mozhe opisati kretanje
tela \textbf{pri nerelativistichkim brzinama}, tj. pri brzinama mnogo
manjim od brzine svetlosti.

\end{document}
```

[image]